How to fix react native dependency versions to correct ones?
The following packages should be updated for best compatibility with
the installed expo version:
@shopify/react-native-skia@1.3.10 - expected version: 1.2.3
  react-native-svg@15.4.0 - expected version: 15.2.0
  react-native-webview@13.10.5 - expected version: 13.8.6

Your project may not work correctly until you
install the expected versions of the packages.
npx expo-doctor

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This will update your packages to match the installed Expo version.
npx expo install --check

